# jQuery Datatable Show / hide columns dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to show/hide datatable columns dynamically. For this, here I am going with the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) which is given by the official datatable website.

This is the code for my datatable:

HTML:

```
<table id="itemEdit" class="table collapsed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var tableId = "#itemEdit";
var $_table = $(tableId).DataTable({ 
    //dom:            "Bfrtip",
    scrollY:        "300px",
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,

    "ajax": './view_items.php',
    "columns": [            
      {"data": "id", "class": "align-middle"},
      {"data": "sku","class": "align-middle"},            
      {"data": "barcode","class": "align-middle"},            
      {"data": "itemname","class": "align-middle"},            
      {"data": "price","class": "align-middle"},            
    ]
})
```

HTML for `<a>`:

```
<div class="btn-group dropright dd-backdrop">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Columns</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0 ">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item toggle-vis" data-column="4">
        Item Name
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is, just I want to add `CSS` class for the `a.toggle-vis` base on its visibility.

I tried it something like this. But its not working for me.

```
$('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the column API object
    var column = $_table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));

    //console.log(column)

    if (column.visible() === true) {
      $(this).addClass('showing').removeClass('not-showing');
      column.visible(!column.visible());
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('showing').addClass('not-showing');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
       
    $_table.columns.adjust().draw( false ); // adjust column sizing and redraw
});
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: do you mean `$_table.column()` or `table.column()`?

Comment: $_table.column() is correct with my code

Comment: Your code works for me, using the demo you linked to. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Just to note: (a) You don't need `if (column.visible() === true`), you can just use `if (column.visible())` - that will evaluate to `true` or `false`. And (b) Did you pre-populate your `<a>` elements with the initial extra class `showing`?  Finally (c) I am not sure what `$(this).removeClass('active');` achieves since that class does not exist in the page (at least not in the demo you linked to ).

Comment: @andrewJames According to your comment: (a) I just tried `if (column.visible())` then its working at first,  but then its not working and I can't get the column visible. (b) I need those `css` classes to style `<a>` based on its visibility. (c) actually its not needed

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: OK - thank you for the updates. That's not a MRE, however. I am still unable to recreate your problem, even with some guesswork.

Comment: @andrewJames, Once again, I updated my question and posted all ralavant code for my table

Comment: Try this: Move `column.visible(!column.visible());` to before the `if` statement. It needs to always be executed. So, that was actually in your question from the start and I automatically "fixed" it when I wrote my version of your approach - sorry about that - that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, your approach is correct - with one small change: Move the following line (which toggles the column's visibility)...

```
column.visible(!column.visible());
```

...from inside the `if` statement to before the `if` statement.

That will ensure the toggle always happens for the selected column.